# reading from serial ports in c#

Tags: c#, binary, serial-communication

i have been struggling to do this for weeks and get all different types of results from some data to none at all, exceptions with code and faults. I am currently trying to write an app that sends a command to a serial port then waits for a response, i can send commands correctly but getting the return data is an issue. after a command is sent it should return a series of bytes in blocks of 256 and put them in a byte[] array until a set amount is reached, e.g. 4096 bytes in 256 byte chunks. then pass array back so that i can save to a file, i can open create and save a binary file so no problems there just with serial port stuff, i have read lots and lots of serial port stuff and none of it seems to be concise.

i have made a gui and this is code so far try not to mind the mess as i said i am struggling and code is all over the place. I am using Visual Studio 2019 C#, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace SerialApp1
{
    public partial class FormSerial : Form

    {
        int bytread;
        public byte[] spbuf;
        bool DataAvailable;
        int sport_NumberOfBytesRead;

        public FormSerial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetAvailablePorts();
            byte[] spbuf = new byte[256];

        }

        void GetAvailablePorts()
        {
            String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            cBoxPorts.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }

        //Serial stuff*****************************************************

        void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object Sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.BytesToRead != bytread) // Wrong number of bytes
                return;                                 // Does nothing
            spbuf = new Byte[bytread];
            // Try to read the data
            try { sport_NumberOfBytesRead = serialPort1.Read(spbuf, 0, bytread); }
            // If error, return failure
            catch (Exception) { sport_NumberOfBytesRead = -1; }
            DataAvailable = true;                       // Break read loop
        }

         void SerialPort1_ErrorReceived(object Sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            sport_NumberOfBytesRead = -1;               // Flag error occurred
            DataAvailable = true;             // Break wait loop
        }

        void GetData(byte[] Buffer, int Len)//, int Nbr)
        {
            DataAvailable = false;                    // No data yet
            bytread = Len;                      // Bytes to read
            do
            {                                        // Wait till data is available
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            } while (!DataAvailable);
            Buffer = spbuf;              // Pass the returned data to the caller
            //Nbr = bytread;   // Return the number of bytes read
        }


        //*********************************************************************************



        private void btnOpenP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(cBoxPorts.Text==""||cBoxBaud.Text=="")
                {
                    textBReceive.Text="Please select port settings";
                }
                else
                {
                    serialPort1.PortName = cBoxPorts.Text;
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxBaud.Text);
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 10;
                    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort1_DataReceived);
                    serialPort1.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort1_ErrorReceived);
                    btnSend.Enabled = true;
                    btnReceive.Enabled = true;
                    btnOpenP.Enabled = false;
                    btnCloseP.Enabled = true;
                    textBSend.Enabled = true;
                    cBoxPorts.Enabled = false;
                    cBoxBaud.Enabled = false;
                    progressBar1.Value = 100;
                }                
            }
            catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                textBReceive.Text = "Unauthorized Access";
            }
        }

        private void btnCloseP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();            
            btnSend.Enabled = false;
            btnReceive.Enabled = false;
            btnOpenP.Enabled = true;
            btnCloseP.Enabled = false;
            textBSend.Enabled = false;
            cBoxPorts.Enabled = true;
            cBoxBaud.Enabled = true;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //serialPort1.WriteLine(textBSend.Text);
            string nl = Environment.NewLine;
            string sts;
            sts = ("R," + textBSAd.Text + "," + textBLng.Text + "," + textBLWdt.Text + nl);
            serialPort1.WriteLine(sts);
            textBSend.Text = "";
            //GetData(spbuf, Convert.ToInt32(textBLng.Text), sport_NumberOfBytesRead);
            //GetData(spbuf, 256);
            try
            {

            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text + nl + "Timeout Exception");
                //textBReceive.Text = "Timeout Exception";            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType().ToString()); //will print System.NullReferenceException for example
            }

            //for (int i = 0; i <= sport_NumberOfBytesRead; i++)//spbuf.Length - 1
            //    {
             //       if (i % 8 == 0) { textBReceive.Text = textBReceive.Text + nl + i.ToString("X3") + ": "; }
              //      textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text += spbuf[i].ToString("X2"));
              //      textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text += " ");
               // }
        }

        private void btnReceive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nl = Environment.NewLine;
            int nbrtr = 256;
            try
            {

                //ReadSerialdata(nbrtr);
                textBReceive.Text = textBReceive.Text + serialPort1.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text + nl + "Timeout Exception");
                //textBReceive.Text = "Timeout Exception";            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType().ToString()); //will print System.NullReferenceException for example
            }
        }

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        private void btnOBF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            //BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
            byte[] afbytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
            string nl = Environment.NewLine;
            for (int i = 0; i <= afbytes.Length-1; i++)
            {
                if (i % 8 == 0) { textBReceive.Text = textBReceive.Text + nl + i.ToString("X3") + ": "; }
                textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text += afbytes[i].ToString("X2"));
                textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text += " ");
            }
        }

        private void btnSend2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nl = Environment.NewLine;
            string sts;
            sts = ("R," + textBSAd.Text + "," + textBLng.Text + "," + textBLWdt.Text + nl);
            serialPort1.WriteLine(sts);
            //serialPort1.Write(nl);
            //MessageBox.Show(sts);
            try
            {
                ReadSerialdata(256);
                //Fill_Txt_Rec();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text + nl + "Timeout Exception");
                //textBReceive.Text = "Timeout Exception";            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType().ToString()); //will print System.NullReferenceException for example
            }

        }

        public byte[] ReadSerialdata(int numBytes)
        {
            //byte[] spbuf = new byte[numBytes];
            for(int i = 0; i <= numBytes-1; i++)
            {
                spbuf[i] = (byte)serialPort1.ReadByte();
            }
            //serialPort1.ReadByte();
            foreach(byte bytVal in spbuf)
            {
                textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text += (spbuf[bytVal].ToString("X2") + " "));
            }
            return spbuf;
        }

        private void Fill_Txt_Rec()
        {
            string nl = Environment.NewLine;

            for (int i=0; i >= spbuf.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 8 == 0) { textBReceive.Text = textBReceive.Text + nl + i.ToString("X3") + ": "; }
                textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text += spbuf[i].ToString("X2"));
                textBReceive.Text = (textBReceive.Text += " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thankyou,

sorry for the non clarity

the bit I am having trouble with is reading bytes sequentially into a byte array from the serial port than passing that byte array back to the calling function. I need the app to send a command to the serial port than wait for the returning data which is raw bytes to be returned, the device has no problems receiving commands and sending back the data, its just the c# side reading the information back.

Comment: Hi,  what exactly are you struggling with, it wasnt clear in  your question

Comment: `bytread` seems to be uninitialized. It is only set in `GetData` - which is never called.  Hence your `DataRecieved` probably would not work as expected. also you are recreating the buffer every time, throwing away any old data in it. Probably not what you need it to do.

Comment: thanks, will look into this(DataRecieved) more